# releasing file handle on image

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am saving an image file, then using Image namespace to resize the image.

The problem is that from the point of when image is saved to the system, to the point where image resizing is handled, the file handle seem not to get released right away, giving me error "A generic error occurred in GDI+"

Here is my code:

I am using asyncfileupload ajax control, C# in VS 2008

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("./") + "abc.jpeg");

//File handle seems not get released right away here.            

System.Drawing.Image FullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("./") + "abc.jpeg");
System.Drawing.Image NewImage = FullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(60, 60, null, IntPtr.Zero);

NewImage.Save(Server.MapPath("./") + "abc.jpeg");
```

Answer (score 2):

System.Drawing.Image is Disposable, you need a using statement.

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("./") + "abc.jpeg");

System.Drawing.Image NewImage = null;
//File handle seems not get released right away here.
using(System.Drawing.Image FullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("./") + "abc.jpeg"))
    NewImage = FullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(60, 60, null, IntPtr.Zero);

using(NewImage)
    NewImage.Save(Server.MapPath("./") + "abc.jpeg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use Dispose function to clean up everything. For example

FullsizeImage.Dispose();